# Drawing an image on top of an image in a JComponent erases part of the bottom image

Tags: java, image, swing, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

I am making a 2d game and I need to draw an image on top of another. After I draw the first image(the larger one, jpg), the second image(the smaller one,png) erases from where the second image is to the lower right hand corner. Like this:

[image]

I have looked into this a bit, and it was suggested that I use buffered images, so I did that with both images and the problem remains. Here is one post I looked at: [How to draw an image over another image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055005/how-to-draw-an-image-over-another-image). I have also seen some people suggesting graphics2d, though I did not really understand the reason to use them or how to use them. I am new to java graphics and images, so it is probably a silly mistake. 
Here is my code. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DisplayExample extends JComponent
{
private BufferedImage backgroundImage;
private String backgroundName;

private BufferedImage image;  //image to draw
private int imageX;  //position of left edge of image
private int imageY;  //position of top edge of image

private JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DisplayExample example = new DisplayExample();
    example.run();
}

public DisplayExample()
{
    imageX = 200;
    imageY = 200;

    backgroundName = "backgroundShip.jpg";
    URL backgroundURL = getClass().getResource(backgroundName);
    if (backgroundURL == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load:  " + backgroundName);
    try{backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(backgroundURL);}catch(IOException ioe){}
    //load image

    String fileName = "explosion.png";
    URL url = getClass().getResource(fileName);
    if (url == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load:  " + fileName);
    //image = new ImageIcon(url).getImage();
    try{image = ImageIO.read(url);}catch(IOException ioe){}
    System.out.println(image instanceof BufferedImage);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1040,500));  //set size of drawing region

    //need for keyboard input
    setFocusable(true);  //indicates that WorldDisp can process key presses

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(backgroundImage != null)
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g.drawImage(image, imageX, imageY, this);  
}

public void run()
{ 
    while(true)
    {
    imageY+=1;
    repaint();
    try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you want transparency of the images I recommend using `.png`. Also make sure that they are saved with transparent background. That being said, I am taking a more thoroughly look on your code.

Comment: You code works okay for me, could be the images?  You are running the risk of blocking the Event Dispatching Thread and a Swing `Timer` might be a better solution for updating the UI. Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Comment: `Graphics2D` is an enhanced extension of `Graphics` which provides a number of really neat features, Shape, transformations, composites, etc. Have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details. When painting in Swing, you are passed an instance of `Graphics2D`, you just need to cast the instance `Graphics`  to it

Comment: Oh, you should also be starting your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread as well, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: On my test,  the second image does not erase the background image.

Comment: The problem was with the images. I knew it was something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took your code, added my own images and it runs fine for me.

Having said that, there are some areas you can improve:

- You're running the risk of either blocking the Event Dispatching Thread or introducing a thread race condition into your code with your `run` method.  You should consider using a Swing `Timer` instead.  See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.  This allows you to schedule regular callbacks which are called within the context of the EDT, making it safer to update the context of the UI
- You should only ever create or modify the state of the UI from within the context of the EDT, Swing is not thread safe.  See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.  Swing has been known to have "issues" when the UI is not initialised within the EDT
- Scaling an image is expensive, you should avoid doing so from within the `paint` methods, instead, scale the image and keep a reference to the result and use it when you need to paint it.
- You should consider using the key bindings API over `KeyListener`, it will solve many of the issues associated with using `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

For example...

[image: Pony Up]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DisplayExample extends JComponent {

    private BufferedImage backgroundImage;
    private String backgroundName;

    private BufferedImage image;  //image to draw
    private int imageX;  //position of left edge of image
    private int imageY;  //position of top edge of image

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DisplayExample example = new DisplayExample();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(example);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public DisplayExample() {
        imageX = 200;
        imageY = 200;

        try {
            backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        //load image

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        //need for keyboard input
        //setFocusable(true);  //indicates that WorldDisp can process key presses
        // Use the key bindings API instead, causes less issues
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                imageY += 1;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return backgroundImage == null ?  new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(), backgroundImage.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (backgroundImage != null) {
            // Scaling is expensive, don't do it here
            int x = (getWidth() - backgroundImage.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - backgroundImage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(backgroundImage, x, y, this);
        }
        g2d.drawImage(image, imageX, imageY, this);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my code. Turns out it was a silly mistake. The smaller image was not on a transparent background, so it was actually working the entire time.